# Can I break encapsulation/data hiding with namespaces (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, mono, namespaces, encapsulation

If I am making a .Net dll, is it possible to break encapsulation in any program that uses it, by creating a class with the same namespace?

For example, consider a DLL with the following code in it:

```
using System;

namespace MyDLL
{
    internal class MyClass
    {
        internal void Stuff()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If I was to then create a project, and reference the DLL, would I be able to do something like the following?

```
using System;
using MyDLL;

namespace MyDLL
{
    public class TheirClass
    {
        MyClass exposedClass = new MyClass();
        exposedClass.Stuff();
    }
}
```

I'm currently working on a project that will have a few abstract classes I want a user to be able to inherit, but I only want to certain features to be exposed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, using the same namespace have no impact on data encapsulation nor any impact on visibility (private/protected/internal). Namespaces are syntactic sugar in C#, actual class names consist of namespace, name and assembly identity.

So in your particular case adding class with full name `MyDLL.TheirClass{TheirAssembly}` will not make `MyDLL.MyClass{MyDLL}` visible from `TheirClass` (since your class is internal and new class is from other assembly not marked as `InternalsVisibleTo` in your assembly).

Comment: Thanks, this has answered my question